# Voted for reopening a question

Tags: discussion, support, reopen

I voted to reopen this question: [Guild Wars 2 Digital Deluxe items acquisition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/guild-wars-2-digital-deluxe-items-acquirisation)

which I believe is different from [What are the gameplay implications for each of the Digital Deluxe items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94144/what-are-the-gameplay-implications-for-each-of-the-digital-deluxe-items)

The first one asks and has an answer about how to get the Digital Deluxe items. As additional information is provided which items are accountbound and which are characterbound.

The second question is about what the items are and what they will do. That's why I voted to reopen.

Comment: I don't get it, what's the problem you're facing here?

Comment: I'd assume the problem is that he needs 4 more reopen votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've cast one vote, this will get brought to the attention of other users automatically through the Review Queue and other more subtle indicators. You don't need to (and shouldn't) bring it up on Meta. If everyone posted a new Meta question every time they cast a vote to reopen a question, Meta would be flooded and rendered useless.

Comment: Wait a minute... Meta is currently useful? :)